# App Crashing When Intent to Launch Activity Called

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am a beginner using Android Studio to Create an application.

On my homepage/ActivityMain I wish to put a textView that when clicked, will launch into another RelativeLayout activity.

I have attempted to do this using an intent, but the application crashes when the textbox is clicked.
Please note that for all code, statements which I believe to be irrelevant were deleted (import, bundle)
Below is my code for activity_main.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Organelles" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/membrane"
    android:text="Cell Membrane"
    android:onClick="explainCellMembrane" />
```

Below is my code for MainActivity.java containing the code containing my intent:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

        public void explainCellMembrane(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MembraneActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
}
```

Below is the code for the Class(MembraneActivity) launched by the intent:

```
    package com.example.android.cellularbiology;

public class MembraneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_membrane);
    }

}
```

Finally is my code for the layout of my custom Java Class:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Membrane Explanation Page"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In AndroidStudio there are no errors (red underline)
When the app crashes it does not show error, just says that it has stopped.

How do I fix my intent? Or should another method be used?

Thanks for your help.

Android Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.cellularbiology">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logs:

```
    01/03 00:06:12: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of /Users/FideronTSANG/Desktop/CellularBiology/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.example.android.cellularbiology
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.android.cellularbiology/com.example.android.cellularbiology.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 24150 on device samsung-sm_c9000-b9dec0e1
Application terminated.
```

Conclusion:
Thankyou everyone for answering and helping out a noob!
You completely saved my project!
I hope you have a nice day :)

The intent worked after I added

```
<activity
    android:name = ".MembraneActivity">
</activity>
```

To my android manifest.

I also used the improved intent provided by

```
public void explainCellMembrane(View view) {

    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MembraneActivity.class));

}
```

Comment: Check your logcat. Any `fatal` error ?

Comment: Add your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: try clean and rebuild project

Comment: Add your second activity to manifest file

Comment: your last layout file where is Linear Layout property?

Comment: Question is unclear. Add your manifest file or logcat message here

Answer (score 1):

**First** of all replace your `explainCellMembrane` method with this:

```
public void explainCellMembrane(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MembraneActivity.class));

    }
```

**Second,**  Try **Cleaning and Rebuilding** your project and then share your `logCat` in the question.

**EDIT:**
After checking your `logCat` I can see the error is not in your `logCat` but it is in the device so try deleting the application in your emulator or mobile device and then install it again through Android-Studio, this works for me too as it often occurs randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class to your manifest.

Add the following...

```
<activity android:name=".MembraneActivity"></activity>
```

This will go under the `</activity>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no problem with your `Intent`. And the problem is you are missing to add your `MembraneActivity` in the `Manifest` file, that will go under `<activity><activity/>` tag. For example,

```
<activity
    android:name = ".MembraneActivity">
</activity>
```

Whenever you add a new `Activity` in your app, you must have to add the `Activity` name in the `Manifest` file. Otherwise you app will not recognize the `Activity` you are trying to start through the `Intent` `myIntent`.

Now after adding the `MembraneActivity` in the `Manifest` file, it will be like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.android.cellularbiology">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <activity 
                android:name=".MainActivity">

                <intent-filter>
                    <action 
                        android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category
                        android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>

            <!--your missing activity added here-->
            <activity
                android:name = ".MembraneActivity">
            </activity>

        </application>
    </manifest>
```